# python flask import. import error unknown location

Tags: python, flask, visual-studio-code, python-import, importerror

i am trying to import create_app from **init**.py that is located in the website file
but everytime I try to run the code I get

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'create_app' from 'website' (unknown location)
```

this is my files

```
.vscode
env
website
   --static
   --templates
   --__init__.py
   --auth.py
   --views.py
   --models.py
main.py
```

**init**.py

```
from flask import Flask
def create_app():
    app = Flask(__name__)
    app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'hello'
    return app
```

main.py

```
from website import create_app
app = create_app
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

thought this is the only method that isn't working I tried this method to check if the error is from vscode but it is just from this method
I tried
app.py

```
from flask import Flask 
app = Flask(__name__)
@app.route("/")
def home():
    return "hello Flask"
```

and when I write in the terminal `python -m flask run
I would get a website that says "hello Flask"
but when I press the run icon I get nothing

unlike the first one if I run it I would get an import error unknown location
and if I use `python -m flask run I would get`

```
Error: could not locate a Flask application. You did not provide the "FLASK_APP" environment variable, and a "wsgi.py" or "app.py" module not found in the current directory.
```

thought everything is sync to Github
in both of them I am working in a 'script' environment

Comment: From which path are you running the application? Python adds the directory you are running the script from to the sys.path and unless your custom packages are located in a subdir to that path, Python won't find it.

It probably works if you add the project root dir to env variable PYTHONPATH

Comment: Another thing is that in main.py you never call the create_app method, so you need to add () after the function name, otherwise you are just giving the app variable a reference to that function.

Answer (score 1):

A fix I came up with was adding **name** to the function defining create_app inside the init file.
Example:

from flask import Flask

def create_app(**name**):
app = Flask(**name**)

Answer (score 0):

When importing, try `from website.templates import create_app`. So basically after you put it to import from website, add `.` following the sub-folder that you desired to import from (in this case it is `templates`).

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same thing, but it appears that these files "models, views, etc" isn't in website folder, they are inside static folder which is in website folder, that's why it's not working.
I just fixed them manually.

Answer (score 0):

For someone getting this error later (like myself), be sure to check that your main package's

```
__init__.py
```

file is in the correct place.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot create environment variable.
if you using mac or linux `export FLASK_APP=main.py`
if you windows `set FLASK_APP=main.py`

And last in main.py should be `app = create_app()`

Answer (score 0):

try this
in your main.py

```
from website.init import create_app
```

or
change file init to *init*.py
then in your main.py

```
from website._init_ import create_app
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the fix.

Your `__init__.py` shouldn't be in the templates folder, move it out to the website folder.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to Fix it.

It is simple  you will be surprised,
Just Go to you file **init**.py and run it first before you go run your main.py and run it.

I think the problem rises from the fact that both file after importing were not run.
So after importing you must run all your files.

I hope it works.

Answer (score 0):

#### Folder Structure:

```
.vscode/
env/
website/
   -- static/
   -- templates/
   -- __init__.py
   -- auth.py
   -- views.py
   -- models.py
main.py
```

**Correct Import Statement:**

```py
from website.template import create_app
```

importing `create_app` function from `website.template` module solved this cause __init__.py is inside website/template/__init__.py

The import statement in `main.py` was:

```py
from website import create_app
```

This statement suggests that `create_app` is directly inside the `website` package, but in your actual folder structure, it is inside the `website.template` module.